# Error Submitting PDF's using SolrJ and Solr 5.1.0

Tags: java, solr, solrj, apache-tika

I'm using Solr to pull information from a Database and a file system simultaneously. The database houses the file path of the file in the file system. It pulls all of those just fine. In fact, it combines the metadata from the database and the metadata from the file system great. The problem occurs when I try to index the text using Apache Tika. The error does not occur at the point when it tries to add the field "text" to the document. The error occurs when I try to submit that document to Solr. It gives me this error,

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id /some/filepath to the index; possible analysis error.

This is how the field is defined in schema:

and this is the code I use to add it to the document:

```html
File file = new File(filepath); 

ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler(); 

Metadata metadata = new Metadata(); 

ParseContext context = new ParseContext(); 

Input Stream = new FileInputStream(file); 


  try{ 

     autoParser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, context); 
  
  } catch (Exception e) { 

      //prints out error message 

       continue; 

  } 


  if(textHandler != null){ 

    doc.addField("text",textHandler.toString()); 

  } 

  try{ 
  
    server.add(doc); 

  } catch (Exception ex){ 

   //logmessage 

       continue; 

  }
```

I think it has something to do with how the field is defined in schema but I don't know. All the files that get error messages are PDF's if that helps. There are .doc s in the file system but they don't error out.

this is the stack trace

```html
/home/paden/Documents/LWP_Files/BIGDATA/5974412.pdf
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/Testcore3: Exception writing document id /home/paden/Documents/LWP_Files/BIGDATA/5974412.pdf to the index; possible analysis error.
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:556)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:139)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:153)
    at TikaSqlIndexer.Index(TikaSqlIndexer.java:238)
    at TikaSqlIndexer.main(TikaSqlIndexer.java:85)
```

And this is the full schema file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<schema name="example" version="1.5">
  

 

 
   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 
   <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="filepath" type="string" indexed="true" stored ="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />  
   <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored ="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />  
   <field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored ="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />  
   <field name="text" type="string" indexed="true" stored ="false" required="false" multiValued="true" />  
   <field name="key" type="string" indexed="true" stored ="false" required="false" multiValued="false" /> 

 
   
   <dynamicField name="*_name"  type="text_general"   multiValued="false" indexed="true"  stored="true" />

   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>


   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />

   <dynamicField name="*_dt"  type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

 
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />



 <uniqueKey>filepath</uniqueKey>


    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />


    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

 
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

  
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>


    <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

 
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />


    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    
 
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

  
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

   
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
             possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

   
    <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
           maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

   
    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
      
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
       
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

  
    <fieldType name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />

   
    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d"/>

  
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>

   
    <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
        geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.001" distanceUnits="kilometers" />

   
    <fieldType name="bbox" class="solr.BBoxField"
               geo="true" distanceUnits="kilometers" numberType="_bbox_coord" />
    <fieldType name="_bbox_coord" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" docValues="true" stored="false"/>

  
    <fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" precisionStep="8" defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currency.xml" />

</schema>
```

Just rolling out a little bit more information as it is coming. I changed the field type in the schema to text_general and that didn't change a thing.

Another thing is that it's consistently submitting/not submitting the same documents. I will run over it one time and it won't index a set of documents. When I clear the index and run the program again it submits/doesn't submit the same documents.

And it will index certain PDF's it just won't index others. Which is weird because I printed the strings that are submitted to Solr and the ones that get submitted are really similar to the ones that aren't submitted.

I can't post the actual strings for sensitivity reasons.

Comment: Can you provide some more information?What version of solr are you using? Can you paste the entire error stacktrace? Also the schema file.

Comment: Information has been added. Let me know if you need more. Thanks

Comment: You have file path as uniqueKey. Are all your file paths unique?

Comment: Yes. Each file path maps to a different document. There are no duplicates.

Comment: This ONLY happens when I include the "text" field. If I add another field from the document I am indexing say, author, it indexes just fine. I only get errors on the text.

Comment: The other fields are Meta data right? Not text extracted using Tika? I see you are using a autoParser, I am assuming you are AutoDetectParser. Can you specify the PDF parser explicitly and see if that helps?

Comment: tried the PDF parser. Same result. same exact number of documents submitted/not submitted